# Speeding Up Angular Material Autocomplete or Alternatives

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

I am using Angular Materials autocomplete to allow a user to search a string of the format: "[ID #] - [Textual Description]".
The data is pre-retrieved at the very beginning of the page loading and holds approximately 39,000 strings.

My HTML code is:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="TSN Search" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="TSN_Ctrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let tsn of filtered_TSNs | async" [value]="tsn">
        {{ tsn }}
    </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

And my typescript code is:

```
TSN_Ctrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
filtered_TSNs: any;

constructor(){
    this.filtered_TSNs = this.TSN_Ctrl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(val => val ? this.filter_TSNs(val) : this.dataService.tsnTitles.slice());
}

private filter_TSNs(val: string) {
    return this.dataService.tsnTitles.filter(option => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(option));
}
```

I am essentially using the standard code from the Angular Materials example, with a slight adaptation.

The autocomplete function is incredibly slow and essentially non-responsive.  I understand there are a lot of options (39k strings) but it is pre-retrieved and locally stored.

Is there something I can do to speed this up or are there simply too many strings in the list?  If I modify the filter method and strings to only contain the ID field, could that speed up the process?  Do I need to use an entirely different library (i.e. if Angular Materials Autocomplete is known to be slow)?

Comment: Try adding `console.time` to your `filter_TSNs` method to see how long each filter is taking, though I expect it to be pretty fast. The true culprit is probably the autocomplete/angular trying to render 39k option components (!) You may want to return a subset in  `filter_TSNs` (like the first 50 options)

Comment: Will, you are a genius.  I ended up only running the filter_TSNs function once the user has inputted at least 5 characters.  The subsets returned after the first 5 characters are drastically reduced (50 or so) and the issue was with autocomplete/angular, not the filter function itself.

Answer (score 5):

Will Howell's advice of "The true culprit is probably the autocomplete/angular trying to render 39k option components (!) You may want to return a subset in filter_TSNs (like the first 50 options)" was the issue and should be the accepted answer.  By limiting the search function to only display autocompleted results until the 4th character, the autocomplete became instantaneous.

Comment: For those who may ask, you can acheive this by doing:  `.map(val => val.length >= 4 ? this.filter_TSNs(val) : []);`

Answer (score 4):

An other solution would be to use the [Virtual Scroll from the Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview).

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="48" style="height: 256px">
        <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let tsn of filtered_TSNs | async" [value]="tsn">
          {{ tsn }}
        </mat-option>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

The `height: 256px` is important, otherwhise you will not see it.

Comment: Thank you, I think this solution is more elegant )

Comment: **UPDATE:** currently there are some problems with using virtual scroll inside **MatAutocomplete**, [here is description](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10122)

Answer (score 0):

Filtering after checking the value length made this work as [PeekYou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478016/peekyou) mentioned

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)